# Can't access label in user control on Master page from Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to update a label in a user control on a Master Page after a partial postback from Javascript.  The problem I am having is actually accessing the control.

User control on Master Page looks like this:

```
<uc:Header runat="server" ID="Header1" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

HTML of User control looks like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlHeader" runat="server" CssClass="page-head">
<h2>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Title"></asp:Label></h2>
```

In my Javascript, I am capturing the partial postback using:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(updateHeader);

function updateHeader() {

    alert(document.getElementById('<%=(Master.FindControl("Header1")).ClientID %>'));

}
```

Header1 comes back null.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: in which moment are you loading the <%=(Master.FindControl("Header1")).ClientID %>, that's a razor server side request, it can only be populated during the server side rendering,

Comment: It's webforms not MVC.  The Master Page loads when the page loads.  The problem is that I need to change the label on a partial postback.

Comment: Header1 is a user control and it is not rendered; the contents is render.  That is why Header1 is null ie not found.  Take a look at the source html.  JavaScript cannot see it.  You could give lblTitle a cssclass of title and then address it via javascript: document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0].innerHTML);

Answer (score 0):

You need to use FindControl a second time to locate the Label inside the User Control.

```
<%= Master.FindControl("Header1").FindControl("lblTitle").ClientID %>
```